# MySQL stored procedure - distinguish between note and error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-drop

I have a stored procedure that executes stored SQL.

However, the error-handler kicks-in and exits if the user attempts to execute

```
drop temporary table if exists t_person;
```

and '`t_person`' doesn't exist. I'm perfectly happy to generate an error when '`if exists`' is not given, but how do I avoid an error for the earlier case (the error-code is unchanged)?

Here's my error handler:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  set @sql = 'select \'Invalid SQL or bad parameter resulting in invalid SQL\' as `Error`';
  prepare stmt from @sql;
  execute stmt;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CONTINUE` handler rather an an `EXIT` handler that catches MySQL error 1051 "Unknown table"...

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1051 BEGIN END;
```

-or-

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42S02' BEGIN END;
```

**EDIT**

To catch a MySQL error in an exception handler, you need to specify the MySQL error number or the corresponding SQLSTATE to be caught. (You could specify a named condition, but that named condition has to resolve to a MySQL error number or SQLSTATE).

A syntax error would throw MySQL error 1064.

If a table `foo` exists, and you issue a

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (id INT);
```

That would throw MySQL error 1050.

To catch that error, declare another handler for that. Assuming you want to "swallow" the exception and continue processing...

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1050 BEGIN END;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

---

<strike>The `like p_person` in the `drop temporary table` statement looks wrong to me; at least, I'm not familiar with using the `LIKE` keyword in a `DROP TABLE` statement.</strike>

Comment: Re: `like_p_person`, I was just wondering the same thing. It is not in the official MySQL documentation, and I can't even think of what function such syntax would serve.

Comment: Apologies - that was copied from a create statement, but I thought an 'if exists' would be clearer than an 'if not exists'... and I made things even more confusing... SOML

Comment: Also, does that let me distinguish between SQL with and without the 'if [not] exists' ?

Mysql knows the difference - it uses a different coloured icon in Query Browser depending on whether the 'if exists' was there or not - but I'm damned if I can distinguish between them.

Comment: TomMelly: `IF NOT EXISTS` isn't valid in a `drop table` statement. That would throw MySQL error 1064. To catch a MySQL error in a handler, you need to specify the MySQL error number or the corresponding SQLSTATE to be caught. (You could specify a named condition, but the condition has to resolve to a MySQL error number or SQLSTATE). Reference: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html)

Comment: Apologies (again). I've complicated matters by not checking the supplied code. Should I replace the text of the original post, or does that just confuse things?

Comment: TomMelly: Its fine to edit your question if those edits clarify your *original* question, by providing additional context and details. That's fine. But it's not okay to *change* the question to an entirely different question. I suspect you're asking about `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. If the table already exists, that statement would throw MySQL error 1050. Declare a separate handler for that error. (I've added to my original answer.)